# Convert "docker run ..." into "docker create ..." && "docker start ..."

Tags: docker

Is there a way to get the docker run command to go into verbose mode and display the exact docker create and docker start commands it runs?

Basically I'd like an automatic way to split docker run commands into the 2 sub commands without me having to map each argument to each sub command.

I've tied -D and --log-level=debug but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to compile docker and add some trace logs to [`api/client/run.go#CmdRun()`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/client/run.go#L42).

That is the method [calling  cli.createContainer()](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/client/run.go#L116) (which is in [`api/client/create.go`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/8f2dca538619372663a94bc5141dbc7f121defb8/api/client/create.go#L80)), and then [starting the container](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/api/client/run.go#L201-L204):

```
//start the container
if _, _, err = readBody(cli.call("POST", "/containers/"+createResponse.ID+"/start", nil, nil)); err != nil {
    return err
}
```